# Repetitive color pattern in paragraph in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph tag and I want the text in it to have every other letter orange and the rest of the letters dark orange. The lazy code looks like this:

Html

```
<p>
    <span class='orange'>L</span>
    <span class='yellow'>o</span>
    <span class='orange'>r</span>
    <span class='yellow'>e</span>
    <span class='orange'>m</span>
</p>
```

Css

```
.yellow {
    color: darkorange;
}

.orange {
    color: orange;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g76gr5t4/1/) (Second color turned to blue for noticeability)

How can I make this code look less lazy? I know when you read this question the first time you probably think "Impossible. Can only be done with sorcery.", but I think this should probably be very simple. I'll cope with anything, even a way to make an image repeat across the text.

Comment: Use this `.yellow {
    color: blue;
}` for test. The differences will be more visible. :)

Comment: @curiosu Fine, I just didn't want people thinking I was terrible at UX.

Comment: @showdev Let me clarify. ***ME WANT CSS!!!*** Sorry for not putting that in my original post :(

Comment: You might want to remove the "javascript" tag and the part about "I'll cope with anything". Voting to re-open.

Comment: @showdev What? JavaScript tag? Gah, force of habit :(

Comment: With CSS is just imposible to take the letters inside the `p` tag and make that change... The best you can do is simplify your lazy code avoiding the class names : http://jsfiddle.net/g76gr5t4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you cannot target individual letters of character data content, only elements and a small subset of pseudoelements. You do need markup therefore. You should however **never** use presentational names in classes, that is the job of CSS. So use the anonymous semanticless inline element `<span>` without further details, and then just use advanced CSS selectors:

```
<p>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>m</span>
</p>
```

And CSS:

```
p {
  color:orange;
}
p span:nth-child(odd) {
  color:yellow;
}
```

[Seen here in action](http://jsfiddle.net/n5hscs6o/).

Comment: With this, can't I leave every other letter unwrapped without being a span and leave out `nth-child`?

Comment: Yes, I left all there for sake of completeness but that would also work indeed.

Comment: I know I shouldn't be concerned about this micro-optimization, but can putting everything in a span and removing the setting of color in the paragraph and adding `nth-child(even)` make the css load faster?

Comment: Nope, that will be literally insignificant because of the way CSS is handled by browsers.